# Getting information about a function address

Tags: c++, reflection

Yes, it's one of "these" questions again.

I got a basic reflection framework up and running, although it still requires the front end user to manually register each method (including return type, argument). However I got the idea of making each function virtual which needs to be reflected, as (even though it's compiler dependent) those functions should technically be in the vtable (if not optimized out). So I got to the point where I got the address of each function, and successfully call/execute each. However, is there a way to "get" the return type, and argument types given the address of this function.

Now before you say this is impossible, I don't mind the weirdest way, hackiest way, since I'm only doing this for the challenge. However I do not want preparsing method, or anything similar, as that is not my aim.

Comment: A validly declared function pointer will already carry all those informations. If you cast it to something else, you will simply loose it.

Comment: so... you are parsing the vtable layout? On what platform, and can you post your code?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I do not have a complete function pointer, rather just the address, nothing else.

Comment: This is like asking whether it's possible to find out what a `void*` is pointing to.

Comment: @David Windows, this person explains it much better than I can: http://kaisar-haque.blogspot.co.uk/2008/07/c-accessing-virtual-table.html, I based my version of his

Comment: @zenith It sure sounds like it, which I admit. But it's worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

use a decompiler or a debugger (idapro, ollydebug, windasm ... ) then check how many push there are before the call to that function to guess argument, and try to find what was stored in eax to know what is the return. this is low-level stuff, it is not an easy task at all.

Comment: At best that gets you the size of the return value and, if you're lucky, the size and number of the arguments. Types are somewhat richer than that.

Comment: yes i know, that why i used the keyword 'GUESS'. the best you can do is to guess.  if a tlb is provided then load that typelib and check it (since we are talking about a vtable it is maybe an ActiveX object)

Answer (score 0):

In C++11, you can make your registration and call interface use a template such as:

```
template <class Return, class... Args>
```

You can then specialize it to store type information in the registration function and compare it to the runtime arguments: basically, serialize a type object through template metaprogramming, compare, cast the function pointer to the required type, and call it with the argument list.